# How can I give my text a background color?

Tags: flutter, widget

I want to give color to the text background like the picture below:

[image]

while mine is still like this:

[image]

And the code that I have written is like this:

```
Text(
                'Last Activity',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 16,
                  color: ColorName.whitePrimary,
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: Wrap your Text widget with Container which have a background color

Comment: @Octet That's an overkill, you. can simply set the `style` in the `text` widget. See my below answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
body: Center(
        child: TextButton.icon(
          style: TextButton.styleFrom(
            textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
            ),
          ),
          onPressed: () => {},
          icon: Text('Last Activity'),
          label: Icon(Icons.chevron_right),
        ),
      ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set the `style` parameter in your `Text` widget:

```dart
 Text(
      'Hello, World!',
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32, backgroundColor: Colors.green),
    );
```

[image: Result]

##### See also

- [`TextStyle` (flutter.dev)](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextStyle-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
Text(
  'Last Activity',
  style: TextStyle(
    fontSize: 16,
    color: ColorName.whitePrimary,
    backgroundColor: Colors.indigo[400],
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer below code hope its help to you, I have try 2 ways [`TextButton.icon`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextButton/TextButton.icon.html) and [`Row`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html)

#### 1. Using TextButton Widget

```
   TextButton.icon(
        style: TextButton.styleFrom(
          foregroundColor: Colors.white,
          backgroundColor: const Color.fromRGBO(60, 75, 175, 1),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
          ),
        ),
        onPressed: () => {},
        icon: const Text('Last Activity'),
        label: const Icon(Icons.chevron_right),
      ),
```

Result Using TextButton.icon-> [image]

#### 2. Using Row

```
   GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {},
            child: Container(
              height: 30,//change on your need
              width: 120,//change on your need
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              color: const Color.fromRGBO(60, 75, 175, 1),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: const [
                    Text(
                    'Last Activity',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                    Icon(
                    Icons.chevron_right,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Result Using Row-> [image]

Answer (score -1):

Try the following code:

```
Text(
  'Last Activity',
  style: TextStyle(
    fontSize: 16,
    color: ColorName.whitePrimary,
  ),
),
```

Comment: This changes the actual _text_ color, not the _background_ color